# Issue with passing data from one html to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a variable $var with some value in it in index.php file and i want to access this variable in sample.php after i navigate to sample.php through link. How can i do this with js.

```
$var
<a href="sample.php" class="title">link</a>
```

Comment: if data is not sensitive then you can use `querystring` or else you can use use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this:

index.php

```
<?php $var= "Great";
?>  
<a href="sample.php?data=<?php echo $var;?>" class="title">link</a>
```

In sample.php

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["data"])){
echo $_GET['data'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Tried your first method but, the data is showing in comment after echo in sample.php

Comment: @ChimedPalden : can you please explain more.what is the issue you facing?

Comment: sorry, got my mistake.

Comment: @ChimedPalden :so if it is helpful for you.just upvote my answeer :)

Comment: if $var include "" then it creates problem.

Comment: check $var is empty or not.and if empty put some default value.try this :    <a href="sample.php?data=<?php if (!empty($var)) {
echo $var;
}else { echo "default value"; }?>" class="title">link</a>

Answer (score 1):

```
index.php
$var  = urlencode($var);//in case that the var contains special characters like " ? &
<a href="sample.php?var=<?=$var?>" class="title">link</a>

sample.php
$var = $_GET['var'];
```

OR

```
index.php
$_SESSION['var']=$var;

sample.php
$var = $_SESSION['var'];
```

Comment: I have tried first method .if $var include "" then it creates problem.

Comment: @ChimedPalden i thought that its obvious that you need to check if `$_GET` has the var. `if(isset($_GET['var']))`

Comment: for eg: <a href="sample.php?var=<?=This is the "statement"?>" class="title">link</a> .  In this eg- It will take "This is the" . it will not take "statement coz " is closing <a href="  .I hope u will understand.

Comment: @ChimedPalden you should escape any variable that need to be used in a query string so it won't contain special characters.you need to `urlencode` your var. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

since it's all PHP, meaning on the server side, you are better off putting this in the session as indicated in the second example by Exlord.

If you actually need to use it on the client side, then set it in a session cookie:
example from:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "Alex Porter";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

and retrieve the cookie in javascript:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

```
var x = document.cookie;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to use jquery try the following taking into account you have included the jquery library and have a button to submit the form. This $var can come from a input box. It's not necessary to have a  passing the query string.

```
$("button").click(function(){

  var paramVal = '<?php echo $var; ?>';
  $.post("sample.php",
  {
    varparam:paramVal
  },
  function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
});
```

To retrieve the value you will call the following code in the sample.php:

```
$varParam = $_POST["varparam"];
```